# How to link objects from different directory (running ld)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu, ld

I'm writing simple makefile project.

I'm trying to build the program in two steps:

1. compile source files and save object files in an different directory
2. link the objects into an executable

consider something simple like:

```
all:
    gcc -o ~/some_dir/main.o -c main.c 
    ld -o my_program main.o
```

the problem is the invoke directory isn't "~/some_dir" so ld doesn't find the object file... how can I include "some_dir" in ld search path?

In the more global perspective, I have object files in various directories and I'd like to link them all together using a single linker command file.

Thanks.

Comment: Um, by specifying a usable path to the object to link?  How *else* would you do it?  But any way around, it's generally best to use `gcc` as the linker driver instead of invoking the linker directly: `gcc -o my_program ~/some_dir/main.o`.

Comment: Also, rather than using paths tied to the current user's home directory (`~/some_dir`) it would be much wiser to put built files in locations relative to the working directory for the build, and to locate source files relative to the directory containing the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You're makings things far more complicated than they need to be and should let `make` do more of the work for you. Below is your simple example re-written

```
SRCS=main.c
BUILDDIR=~/somedir
OBJS=$(SRCS:%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)
CFLAGS=-g

all: my_program

my_program: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

It defines a number of variables at the top, such as SRCS which would contain a list of your source files, the directory where you're storing the object files and generates a list of what object files you'll be building. Then it uses `$(OBJS)` to define that they are dependencies of `my_program`. The $@ in the make rule is a variable meaning "the thing that we are building" and $^ is the list of dependencies. You can add other dependencies to `my_program` and don't need to change the command being ran.

Then there is a rule that defines how object files in `$(BUILDDIR)` are built from source files in the current directory.